# Mahapp SplitButton not working correctly

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

In the Mahapp's documentation, `SplitButton` used `binding` to get its datasource. But I just want to add `SplitButton`'s data manually.

```
<controls:SplitButton Grid.Row="3"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
    Width="120"
    DisplayMemberPath="Title"
    VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <controls:SplitButton.Items>
                <Label>1</Label>
                <Label>2</Label>
            </controls:SplitButton.Items>
</controls:SplitButton>
```

However, I'm not able to see the popup window. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `ItemsSource` and an enumerable and don't specify a `DisplayMemberPath`.

```
<controls:SplitButton HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                        Width="120"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <controls:SplitButton.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="system:String">
            <system:String>Label 1</system:String>
            <system:String>Another one</system:String>
            <system:String>Works now</system:String>
        </x:Array>
    </controls:SplitButton.ItemsSource>
</controls:SplitButton>
```

[image]

Hope that works.

Comment: I got `namespace prefix 'system' is not defined.`, how to fix that?

Comment: @zamSunk a bit of a late reply, but this goes in the first line at the top of the xaml file: `xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`

Answer (score 0):

That's because you define your items source twice:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```

and

```
 <controls:SplitButton.Items>
     <Label>1</Label>
     <Label>2</Label>
 </controls:SplitButton.Items>
```

Just remove the `ItemsSource` attribute.

```
<controls:SplitButton Grid.Row="3"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
    Width="120"
    VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <controls:SplitButton.Items>
            <Label>1</Label>
            <Label>2</Label>
        </controls:SplitButton.Items>
</controls:SplitButton>
```

Comment: Actually I did not include it in the first place. Plz have a look @https://www.dropbox.com/sh/k17rcw0dj2tzj4f/AADgN6l2HGRwc8pITIDVrOFTa?dl=0, It's not working

Comment: Then you should update your question, as the sample code provided is incorrect. Furthermore, I don't think that posting links to some dropbox stored code is a good idea. You should provide your code in your question.